# span cannot be a child of tbody in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

um, this doesn't seem right, but consider the following:

```
var InvestmentTransactionsTableRows = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var sliceStart = 0;
    var sliceEnd = this.props.amountToShow

    if (this.props.onCurrentPage !== 1) {
        sliceStart = Math.round(((this.props.onCurrentPage - 1) * this.props.amountToShow));
        sliceEnd = Math.round(this.props.onCurrentPage * this.props.amountToShow);
    }

    var tableRows = this.props.tabData.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd).map(function(tabData) {
      var labelClass = 'label-default';

      switch(tabData.investments.data[0].status) {
        case 'complete':
          return labelClass = 'label-success';
        case 'pending':
          return labelClass = 'label-warning';
        default:
          return labelClass = 'label-default';
      }

      return(
        <tr key={tabData.id}>
          <td>{"$" + tabData.investments.data[0].amount_invested_by_user.toLocaleString()}</td>
          <td>{tabData.full_name}</td>
          <td><span className="label label-default">{tabData.profile.data.investor_type}</span></td>
          <td><span className={"label " + labelClass}>{tabData.investments.data[0].status}</span></td>
          <td>{moment(tabData.updated_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</td>
          <td><a href={"//" + location.hostname + "/admin/issuers-portal/investors/" + tabData.id + "/investments"}>View Transaction</a></td>
        </tr>
      )
    });

    return(<tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>);
  }

});
```

In one of the `td`'s I do:

```
<td><span className={"label " + labelClass}>{tabData.investments.data[0].status}</span></td>
```

I believe its exploding on this. If I replace the `className` with:

```
<td><span className="label label-default">{tabData.investments.data[0].status}</span></td>
```

and comment out the switch case then the world seems to be fine ...

Then everything works.

For this particular loop, the value of: `tabData.investments.data[0].status` is one 'complete' and a bunch of 'incomplete'.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: First of all your are doing a return in your switch function! That will end the function!! We need a working sample, without this it's hard to debug the next step, but try changing the code so you don't use "return" in your switch case!

Comment: `<span className={"label " + labelClass}>` – you’ll end up with an unquoted `class` attribute value here.

Comment: Please select an answer if you are satisfied and we have helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: Why are both answers downvoted and nothing is selected as the answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all your are calling return in your switch function! That will end the function!! We need a working sample, without this it's hard to debug the next step, but try changing the code so you don't use "return" in your switch case and see if that fixes the problem, this has not been tested, but I would recommend you try this code:

```
var InvestmentTransactionsTableRows = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var sliceStart = 0;
    var sliceEnd = this.props.amountToShow

    if (this.props.onCurrentPage !== 1) {
        sliceStart = Math.round(((this.props.onCurrentPage - 1) * this.props.amountToShow));
        sliceEnd = Math.round(this.props.onCurrentPage * this.props.amountToShow);
    }

    var tableRows = this.props.tabData.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd).map(function(tabData) {
      var labelClass = 'label-default';

      switch(tabData.investments.data[0].status) {
        case 'complete':
          labelClass = 'label-success';
        case 'pending':
          labelClass = 'label-warning';
        default:
          labelClass = 'label-default';
      }

      return(
        <tr key={tabData.id}>
          <td>{"$" + tabData.investments.data[0].amount_invested_by_user.toLocaleString()}</td>
          <td>{tabData.full_name}</td>
          <td><span className="label label-default">{tabData.profile.data.investor_type}</span></td>
          <td><span className={"'label " + labelClass + "'"}>{tabData.investments.data[0].status}</span></td>
          <td>{moment(tabData.updated_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</td>
          <td><a href={"//" + location.hostname + "/admin/issuers-portal/investors/" + tabData.id + "/investments"}>View Transaction</a></td>
        </tr>
      )
    });

    return(<tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>);   }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

As other's mentioned, you don't need to return in your switch statement, just set the `labelClass` variable.  Try this:

```
 switch(tabData.investments.data[0].status) {
    case 'complete':
      labelClass = 'label-success';
    case 'pending':
      labelClass = 'label-warning';
    default:
      labelClass = 'label-default';
  }
```